# Can't insert spaces in code editors

Tags: editor, ubuntu-12.04, codeblocks, mysql-workbench, codelite

Since i recently installed CodeBlocks, I can't insert spaces in codeblocks, codelite or mysql-workbench editors.
When i press space the editor interprets it as a completion key unless there is no word to complete.
The only way to insert a blank space is to press "Supper+Space".
I tried to remove CodeBlocks and CodeLite but the problem persists in Mysql Workbench.
Configuration : 
uname -a :

```
Linux slxpc 3.2.0-57-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 21:35:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

cat /proc/version

```
Linux version 3.2.0-57-generic (buildd@toyol) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #87-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 21:35:10 UTC 2013
```

mysql-workbench --version

```
MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 6.0.8 11354  build 833
```

CodeBlocks version : 10.05

**FYI** : I don't have this problem in geany and leafpad.

Comment: I may need to move this post to unix.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

The common base for these 2 editors (codelite / codeblocks) is that both are using wxWidgets as their underlying GUI toolkit.
So its probably related to this fact.

You failed to mention 2 important details:

- Your keyboard layout ( I assume that you don't use standard keyboard )
- Your codelite version

I can advise you for codelite

Upgrade to the latest version of codelite (which uses a much more recent of wxWidgets). You won't find the latest version of codelite in Ubuntu's repositories since its using an up-to-date version of wxWidgets which is not included by Ubuntu's packagers, you can however, find it in codelite's repository: [codelite download page](http://codelite.org/support.php)

Once installed, it should fix your problem. If the problem persists, change the code completion keyboard shortcut to something else (e.g. Ctrl-ENTER) from Settings -> Keyboard Shortcut

If both methods fails, you can always switch to work with standard keyboard

HTH,
Eran

Comment: By downloading the last version of codelite the problem disappeared for this product but remains for codeblocks and mysql-workbench.

Comment: After days of ties and failures I've just found the cause of my problem, and the solution (It may help someone else): 
I am using a non-US keyboard layout in my case it's a French one. In my Keyboard configuration : 

    MENU -> Parameters -> Keyboard -> Leyout 

I set a "Franch(Variant)" leyout. I just changed it to "French" simply. And the problem disappeared everywhere !
I think CodeBlocks developers and Mysql-workbench ones have to think about this problem though !

Comment: I think that this problem will magically go away for CodeBlocks as well as soon as it switch to wxWidgets 3.0 (they are still using wxWidgets 2.8)